# How can i use conditions to change the response in wordpress ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, twitter

i wrote some code for "Tweet to download" button, but its not working as it should be.

following codes are working but the problem is that when user trigger the click and tweet the provided content, then current page refresh and again display the same button with twitter, although it should display only a downloading link button without twitter icon.

[image]

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_share_to_download', 'share_to_download' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_share_to_download', 'share_to_download' );

function share_to_download() {

    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ritzy_download' ) ) {
        die( 'Busted' );
    }

    echo '<a href="#" id="tweet-to-download-link" class="btn primary">Tweet to Download <span id="tweet-to-download"></span></a>';

    die();
}



add_action( 'wp_ajax_share_to_download_tweet', 'share_to_download_tweet' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_share_to_download_tweet', 'share_to_download_tweet' );

function share_to_download_tweet() {

    $nonce       = $_POST['nonce'];
    $download_id = absint( $_POST['theme'] );

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ritzy_download' ) ) {
        die( 'Busted' );
    }   

    echo '<a href="URL_OF_THE_FREE_THEME_FILE" class="btn primary">Download for Free</a>';

    die();
}
```

And the JQuery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    if ( $('#tweet-to-download-wrap').length ) {
        $.post( ritzy.ajaxurl, {
                action : 'share_to_download',
                theme  : $('#tweet-to-download-wrap').attr('data-theme'),
                nonce  : ritzy.nonce
            }, function( data ) {
                $('#tweet-to-download-wrap').html(data);
                $('#tweet-to-download-link').on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                if( $('#tweet-to-download-link').length ){

                    // First, load the widgets.js file asynchronously
                    window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
                      var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                      if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
                      js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                      return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
                    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

                    twttr.ready(function(twttr){
                        twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
                            $('#tweet-to-download-wrap').attr('data-url'),
                            document.getElementById('tweet-to-download'),
                            function(el){},
                            {
                                count   : 'horizontal',
                                text    : $('#tweet-to-download-wrap').attr('data-content'),
                                related : 'ritzythemes'
                            }
                        );

                        twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(intentEvent){
                            if (!intentEvent) return;
                            $.post(ritzy.ajaxurl, {
                                    action: 'share_to_download_tweet',
                                    theme : $('#tweet-to-download-wrap').attr('data-theme'),
                                    nonce : ritzy.nonce
                                }, function(data){
                                    window.location.reload(true);
                                }
                            );
                        });
                    });

                }
            }
        );
    }

});
```

Comment: need more detail about what is being clicked to cause reload.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I added the image for better understanding. Kindly review and try to resolve my issue. thankful to you.